# How to translate PHTML text including html markup

Tags: magento2, php, template, localisation, internationalization

I'm familiar with how to translate strings including variables such as

```
<?php echo sprintf(__('Hello %s'), $yourVariable) ?>
```

**So what's the cleanest way to translate this example in a PHTML tempalte?**

```
<?php echo __('Please call our Sales Team on '); ?>

<a href="<?php echo __('tel:0123456789')?>">
    <?php echo __('0123456789')?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, Magento Phrase renderer already supports the arguments placeholders and you must not use `sprintf`.

> I'm familiar with how to translate strings including variables such as
>
> ```
> <?php echo sprintf(__('Hello %s'), $yourVariable) ?>
> ```

You must use `__('Hello %1', $yourVariable)` or named placeholders `__('Hello %name', ['name' => $yourVariable])`

---

> So what's the cleanest way to translate this example in a PHTML
>   tempalte?

If your translatable phrase contains simple html markup (such as tags `s`, `a`, `i` without a lot of attributes), then you can include html markup in translate pattern `__('Hello <s>%1</s>', $name)`.

---

In other case you can add your custom renderer for substring and use like

*template.phtml*

```
__('Hello, my dear %longmarkup.', $block->renderCustomerName($customer))
```

*Block.php*

```
public function renderCustomerName(CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $renderer = $this->getChildBlock('customer-renderer');

    return $renderer->setCustomer($customer)->toHtml();
}
```

But I prefer to avoid such cases with complicated translatable string.

Comment: I have never used `sprint_f`, I took that code from the dev docs which is worrying if it shouldn't be used! 

I'll give this a try later and mark as accepted if it works, thanks.